# Calculus on manifold theorem 3-13(change of variable) part 1

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

My question is about the last two line of the proof of the part (1):

[image]

[image]

How did the author proceed from the second last line to the last line?

First I thought he just took the summation into the integral. However, to do so one have to show first that the integrand converge uniformly.

Then I thought the integral defined on the last line may be in the 'extended sense', that is, defined through a series which take the form similar to the second last line. But to do so, I think one must shows that 
$$\{\psi \circ g\} $$ is a partition of unity of the set $A$. I think this is doable but I didn't see it in the proof.

Comment: Doesn't Spivak *define* integration as taking a partition of unity and doing what he does in the second to last line?

Comment: That is what I thought, but to do so i think we should prove that psi circ g is a partition of unity of A first.